# How to autorender a JSON array using pure.js?

Tags: javascript, pure-js

I am trying to use the [pure.js](http://beebole.com/pure/) templating engine to convert a JSON array into HTML code.

I understand how to use `autoRender()` to map an associative map to HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/P7H98/

but if I replace the associative map with an array, I end up with iteration that inserts empty rows: http://jsfiddle.net/P7H98/1/

Is it possible to `autoRender()` an array and end up with the same output as the first example?

**UPDATE**: Nesting `<div class="toString"></div>` inside the `<li>` node fixes the problem. But I'm still not sure why. Surely there is a more readable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toString` is a coincidence.

The property `names` triggers a loop, because it points to an array.
Then the `toString` is a method that exists for each array element, and is called.

If you add the class `toString` on the LI, it will work.

You should try using `render` and directives.
They can be generated on the fly, and give you a more precise control of what needs to be done.